# flink checkpoint stuck on bad file

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am new to flink (1.3.2) and I have a question and want to see if anyone can help here.

So we have a s3 path that flink is monitoring that path to see new files available.

```
val avroInputStream_activity = env.readFile(format, path, FileProcessingMode.PROCESS_CONTINUOUSLY, 10000)
```

I am doing both internal and external check pointing and let's say there is a bad file came to the path and flink will do several retries. I want to take those bad files to some error folders and let the process continue. However, since the file path persisted in the checkpoint, when I tried to resume from external checkpoint (I removed the bad file), it threw the following error on no file been found.

```
java.io.IOException: Error opening the Input Split s3a://myfile [0,904]: No such file or directory: s3a://myfile
```

I have two questions here:

1. How do people handle exceptions like bad file or records.
2. Is there a way to skip this bad file and move on from checkpoint?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Best practice is to keep your job running by catching any exceptions, such as those caused by bad input data. You can then use [side outputs](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.4/dev/stream/side_output.html) to create an output stream containing only the bad records. For example, you might send them to a [bucketing file sink](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.4/dev/connectors/filesystem_sink.html) for further analysis.